# How can I select rows from one table according to condition in the other table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select, where-clause

Here is what my tables look like in a simplified way.

Table **Match** has *match_id*, *host_id*, *away_id*, and the table **Team** has *team_id*, *team_name* columns.

What I want is to select 'match_id', 'host team name', 'away team name'.
I did this using multiple views but there must be something more optimized.

('host team name' and 'away team name' would be the columns with the *team_name* according to related *team_id*)

Comment: So if i understand this correctly `host_id `& `away_id` refers to `team_id` in  the table **Team**?

Comment: Exactly like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join 2 copies of `team` to `match`:

```
select m.match_id, 
       t1.team_name host_team_name, 
       t2.team_name away_team_name 
from match m
inner join team t1 on m.host_id = t1.team_id 
inner join team t2 on m.away_id = t2.team_id
```

Answer (score 0):

A column in a SQL query can itself be a SQL query.

```sql
select (select t.team_name from Team t where t.team_id = m.host_id) as home_team
      ,(select t.team_name from Team t where t.team_id = m.away_id) as away_team
  from Match m;
```

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=88f15670458beb677b7374a6261efa5d)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for sharing this! Might try it in the further queries for the sake of practice.

Comment: @vortex for cases like your problem there exist the joins in sql. Imagine how a query would like if every column was derived by a subquery. This is awful coding.

Comment: @forpas Yeah, it might get messy but it's always cool to know other solutions as well